# Time filtering in django model

Tags: python, django

I wish to perform an operation in the django model where i extract the last 10 minutes of entries and do some data processing on it and return a single value.

I have tried the following code bellow but have not luck. Any help on this would be awesome.

```
class Data(models.Model):
    time_measured = models.DateTimeField(help_text='Time the data was measured.')
    int_val = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2,blank=True)

    def trend(self):
        range_start = self.time_measured.minute - timedelta(minute=10)
        data = Data.objects.filter(time_measured__minute__range=(range_start, self.time_measured.minute))
    return float(data_operation(data.int_val))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd try something like:

```
def trend(self):
    range_start = self.time_measured.minute - timedelta(minute=10)
    data = Data.objects.filter(time_measured__minute__gt=range_start)
return float(data_operation(data))
```

Comment: Thanks @dan-klasson i am having an issue where i cannot output the int value. please see edit above.

Comment: That's because you're getting back a list of querysets. Try `data[0].int_val`

Comment: This function is actually not returning anything.

Answer (score 2):

```
def trend(self):
    range_start = datetime.datetime.now() - timedelta(minutes=10)
    data = Data.objects.filter(time_measured__gte=range_start)
```